# Retrieving only the sixth and seventh matching results in a Rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails app, and I am hitting a roadblock: I need to return several items in a table that are, say, the 6th-8th matching items. Ironically, Rails has a [helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_nth) shown here for `.first` through `.fifth.`

My question is: how can you find these results when the n you are searching for is only 6,7,8 and so on without calling all of the 1st through 8th items?

Here's why I am doing this. I am making a home page for a blog. At the top, I want to show the 5 most recent posts (which will be shown with an image). Underneath them, I want to show an additional three links to posts as text.

Currently, I am doing the first part fine. In my `blog.controller.rb`:

```
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').first(5)
```

I then iterate through Posts in the view, and that shows my first five most recent results. I now want to show the 6th-8th, and I will try and store them in a new method. I change the controller to:

```
    @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').first(5)
    @texts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(8)
```

This returns the 8 most recent posts instead of, say, just the 8th.

Is it possible for me to limit `@texts` to show only the matching 6th, 7th, and 8th results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll want to use offset to get them. Here's the documentation on offset: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset

`Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3).offset(5)`

Comment: This looks promising, and I am looking at the documentation now. Weirdly enough, even with the `limit` parameter, it is returning all of the results in the table (all 9 results when I run locally). I have tried running it with both `Post.order(created_at: :desc).offset(5).limit(3)` and `Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3).offset(5)` (in case it was a relational problem), but no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: If you've got a default scope set on the model it might be interfering with your query. What sql query is being executed? You can see this in your console or in your logs when you run the command. Paste it here if you can't figure out what's going on and I'll have a better idea.

Comment: If it ends up being a default scope problem you can just do `Post.unscoped.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3).offset(5)`

Comment: Good idea. The `.unscoped` didn't fix it, but here's the new output in the console:  `Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 5`. Weird that it is rendering all of them even though it's executing the offset.

Comment: Why is the query executing twice? Is this postgres, mysql or sqlite?

Comment: That's PG. And good question. I think the first is for `@posts` and the second is for `@texts`.

Answer (score -1):

Save some DB time and do it in a single query like this

```
@texts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(8).to_a
@posts = @texts.shift(5) # takes the first 5 records from @texts leaving the remaining 3
```

Comment: Bad idea. DB queries are much faster than Ruby code execution.

Comment: quick benchmark says otherwise for such a simple thing:

Comment: 0.094000   0.000000   0.094000 (  0.125000)
        ==================================================
          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.015621)